# <tr> not displaying correctly in pageblocksection

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:pageblocksection>
            <apex:outputField value="{!displayXml.Customize_Name__c}"/> <br/>
             <apex:pageblocksectionItem rendered="{!displayXml.Customize_Name__c == true}">                  
                <apex:pageblocktable value="{!customiseName}" var="cus" columns="10" style="margin-left:100px;">
               <apex:column headerValue="Field" value="{!cus.ThirdName_Prefix__c}"/>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Text*" value="{!cus.Custom_Text__c}"/>
               </apex:pageblocktable>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" class="data2Col">
                    <span style="color:#328400;font-weight:bold;"> Opportunity Stages </span>   
                    </td>
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" class="data2Col">
                    <table class="detailList">         
                        <tr>
                        <apex:outputtext value="{!displayXml.Oppor_Stage_Name__c}" label="Authorized Transactions"/>                
                        <apex:outputtext value="{!displayXml.Stage_Declined__c}" label="Declined Transactions"/> 

                       <apex:outputtext value="{!displayXml.Stage_Custom_Payment__c}" label="Custom Type Transactions"/>  
                       <apex:outputtext value="{!displayXml.Stage_Invoice__c}" label="Invoice Transactions"/>

                       <apex:outputtext value="{!displayXml.Stage_Free__c}" label="Free Invoice Transactions"/> 
                       <apex:outputtext value="{!displayXml.Stage_PO__c}" label="Purchase Order Transactions"/>


                       </tr>
                       </table>
                  </td>     
                  </tr>
       </apex:pageblocksection>
```

The order is changing whenever their is no rendering.Here is the Image.
[image]

Tried different ways of td & tr nothing worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to have a simple table, try to use `pageBlockSection` with parameter `columns="2"`:

```
<apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
        <apex:outputtext value="Closed Won" label="Authorized Transactions"/>                
        <apex:outputtext value="Closed Lost" label="Declined Transactions"/> 

        <apex:outputtext value="Closed Won" label="Custom Type Transactions"/>  
        <apex:outputtext value="Closed Won" label="Invoice Transactions"/>

        <apex:outputtext value="Closed Won" label="Free Invoice Transactions"/> 
        <apex:outputtext value="Closed Won" label="Purchase Order Transactions"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: awww so simple....didn't noticed it

Comment: I'm sure this wasn't the way it was intended, and clearly OP has no problem with it, but do we really need the "your code is really broken" comments in answers?  If we want people new to the platform to come to this site to learn, this sort of thing may put a few of them off.

Comment: @BobBuzzard Got you Bob.